# Python while if else loop only returns the else value

Tags: python

I have been learning python and I have been 'following' a tutorial to create a simple rock paper scissors game but it only returns the else value from the loop? I have studied their solution (which works fine) however mine doesn't and I can't see any differences?

The website i have used is https://thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-game-rock-paper-scissors/

My code is below:

```
from random import randint

options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

computer = options[randint(0,2)]

player = False

while player == False:
    player == input("Pick one! Rock, Paper or Scissors! ")
    if player == computer:
        print("Unlucky! Its a tie! ")
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("Ohhh unlucky!", computer, "covers", player, "! ")
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer, "! ")
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("Unlucky!", computer, "cuts", player, "! ")
        else:
            print("Nice one!", player, "covers", computer, "! ")
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("Unlucky!", computer, "crushes", player, "! ")
        else:
            print("Nice one!", player, "cuts", computer, "! ")
    else:
        print("Thats not a valid option, please try again! ")
    player = False
    computer = options[randint(0,2)]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Can't work out why its not running properly!

Comment: `player == input(..)` should only have one equals sign: `player = input(..)`.

Comment: Answer in comments above, extra tip. Use sites or tools to check difference: https://www.diffchecker.com/

Comment: Thanks all! That site looks good @Wimanicesir, ill use that next time, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```py
player == input("Pick one! Rock, Paper or Scissors! ")
```

You probably should use `=` here for the assignment, not the `==` comparison operator, so just change it to

```py
player = input("Pick one! Rock, Paper or Scissors! ")
```

Comment: Ahh of course! Thanks so much! So annoying when its something i know and is so simple!

Comment: @MatthewMeek np, happens all the time

Answer (score 2):

A few problems. `player` is used in two different places. `==` is mistaken for `=`, user input is not checked for user trying to quit the game.

```
from random import choice

options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

game_on = True

while game_on :
    computer = choice(options)

    player = input("Pick one! Rock, Paper or Scissors! ")

    if player == computer:
        print("Unlucky! Its a tie! ")
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("Ohhh unlucky!", computer, "covers", player, "! ")
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer, "! ")
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("Unlucky!", computer, "cuts", player, "! ")
        else:
            print("Nice one!", player, "covers", computer, "! ")
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("Unlucky!", computer, "crushes", player, "! ")
        else:
            print("Nice one!", player, "cuts", computer, "! ")
    elif player.lower() == "quit" :
        game_on = False
    else:
        print("Thats not a valid option, please try again! ")
```

Comment: Your code still has the `==` mistake. :-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister ha-ha-ha.... yep, you're right =) fixed now.